# Redirigir dominio a https [Google domain, Heroku, Flask]

Tags: flask, heroku, ssl

Mi pagina web la hice con Flask y la deploye en heroku, el problema es que si buscas 'example.com' si me dirige a la pagina con el protocolo https pero si la buscas como 'www.example.com' me manda a la pagina con http.

¿Que deberia hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Utilice una libreria llamada flask-talisman que nos ayuda a forzar la conexion https.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman